# In Linux it's iwconfig, what about Android

Tags: android, linux, wifi

In Linux I can call `iwconfig` to get the info about wifi spots. How can I obtain the same kind of information in Android?

Comment: Do you want read networks or setup also?

Answer (score 3):

The exact same `iwconfig` exists on Android too. You can connect into your Android phone using `adb shell` over USB and run the `iwconfig` command.

- You can install `adb shell` on your PC. Here is the instruction - http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378
- Connect your Android phone to your PC over UDB
- Open `Command Prompt`
- Run `adb shell` inside the `Command Prompt`
- `adb shell` provides bash like shell to run command on the Android phone. Run `iwconfig` in the `adb shell`

`iwconfig` for Android ia also available from https://github.com/nvamelichev/wireless-tools-android

Answer (score 0):

Android IS almost linux, you can install a terminal program. and run commans (I use JuiceSSH)

There is a command that is in almost all linux, and in Android too (My android have it)

IP Command

You can type ip addr, ip link, ip route and other parameters to set or get your address or other info, like routes